# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)dx=\frac{1}{32}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\gamma-\pi+\ln16)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

Wolfram Alpha provides

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)dx=\frac{1}{32}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\gamma-\pi+\ln16)^2\tag{1}$$

But I haven't figured out the way to verify this result.

I know Frullani's Integral
$$\ln(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}dt$$
I also know 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)~dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\sin(x)~dx$$
Then,
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}dt\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n}-e^{-xn}}{n}dn\right)\sin(x^2)~dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}dt\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n}-e^{-xn}}{n}dn\right)\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}\frac{e^{-n}-e^{-xn}}{n}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}~dx~dn~dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-t}-e^{-xt})(e^{-n}-e^{-xn})\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}~dx~dn~dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-t-n}-e^{-xn-t}-e^{-xt-n}+e^{-xt-xn})\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}~dx~dn~dt
\end{align}$$
What should I do next?
There is also a general case

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x^a)\sin(x^2)dx=\frac{a^2}{32}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\gamma-\pi+\ln16)^2\tag{2}$$

But I think $(2)$ becomes easy to prove if we can prove $(1)$.

Comment: Computer algebra solves this instantly:  $\frac{1}{32} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (2 \gamma -\pi +\log (16))^2$.  Is there really a need to perform this by hand?  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: It is an interesting video. "Hand calculating procedures teach understanding."

Comment: Did you actually watch the full video?  One of Wolfram's key points was exposing the *fallacy* in "hand calculating procedures teach understanding."  Very convincing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't watch the full video. I misunderstood the point.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I entirely disagree. I personally am interested in knowing how to preform such manual calculations as they teach me new techniques which I can apply to other problems. Also, what is the point of knowing that $\int_0^\infty \ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$ has a closed form (or exact evaluation instead of a decimal expansion) if one cannot prove it? Without a proof it is just a useless fact.

Comment: Ok, I see. That is actually a good point. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Very nice integral, especially because of the square in the final expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)dx \overset{x^2=t}=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\sqrt t} \ln^2 (\sqrt t) \sin t dt =\frac18 \int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}\sin t \ln^2 t \,dt$$
Note that the last integral is the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) in $s=\frac12 $ of the sine after being differentiated twice.

See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382412/mellin-transform-for-sin-x) a proof for:
$$\int_0^\infty  x^{s-1}\sin x dx= \Gamma(s) \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac18\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\Gamma(s) \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\bigg|_{s=\frac12}$$
It's not the end of the world to differentiate that twice since the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) comes in our help.

From the wiki page we have:
$\Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{ds}\Gamma(s) \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)=\Gamma(s)\psi(s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) +\frac{\pi}{2}\Gamma(s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\Gamma(s) \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\Gamma(s)\left(\psi(s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)\left(\psi(s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right)+\Gamma(s)\left(\psi_1(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\Gamma(s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right)$$
And now setting $s=\frac12$ we get using $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$, $\psi\left(\frac12 \right)=-\gamma -2\ln 2 $,$\  \psi_1\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$  the result.

Comment: Note that the identity used by @Zacky applied is a direct application of  Ramanujan's Master Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$ F(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^\alpha \sin(x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\alpha/2-1}\sin(x)\,dx\\=\frac{1}{2\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{ds}{s^{\alpha/2}(s^2+1)} $$
by the properties of the Laplace transform. The last integral can be computed through the Beta and Gamma functions, producing
$$ F(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(1+\alpha)\right) $$
for any $\alpha$ such that $\text{Re}(\alpha)\in(-3,1)$. In order to prove the claim, it is enough to apply $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}$ to both sides of the last identity and recall the special values of $\Gamma,\psi$ and $\psi'$ at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let us rewrite your integral as
$$\int_0^\infty \ln^2(x)\sin(x^2)dx=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
To solve this integral, you can employ the following identity, which holds for any $p\in (0,1)$:
$$\int_0^\infty x^{p-1}\sin(x)dx=\Gamma(p)\sin(\pi p/2)$$
The value of your integral can be obtained from this by differentiating both sides of this equation twice with respect to $p$, moving the derivative inside of the definite integral on the LHS, and making use of the known special values of the Digamma function.

This can be done by hand, but it requires a lot of algebra and would be best left to a CAS, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Just a generalization of @Zacky's answer

$$F(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\log^2(x^a)\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$$
Since $\log(x^a)=\log(e^{a\log x})=a\log x$, 
$$F(a)=a^2\int_0^{\infty}\log^2(x)\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$$
$$F(a)=a^2F(1)$$
And as @Zacky showed,
$$F(1)=\frac18\mathrm{D}^2_{s=\frac12}\Gamma(s)\sin\frac{\pi s}{2}=\frac1{32}\sqrt{\frac\pi2}(2\gamma-\pi+\log16)^2$$
So 
$$F(a)=\frac{a^2}{32}\sqrt{\frac\pi2}(2\gamma-\pi+\log16)^2$$

I will edit my answer to include a proof of my own once I find one.

Comment: Nice, I forgot the fact that $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$.

Comment: @Larry I legitimately can't tell if you're being sarcastic or not

Comment: I am not being sarcastic.

Comment: @Larry Thank you for the clarification. You were very right when you mentioned that $(2)$ would be easy to prove once one had proven $(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to employ Feynman's Trick and [Laplace Transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) to solve:

\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^\infty\ln^2(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)\:dx
\end{equation}

We first observe that:

\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^\infty\ln^2(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)\:dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\int_0^\infty x^k\sin\left(x^2\right)\:dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2} H(k)
\end{equation}

We proceed by solving $H(k)$. To do so, we introduce a new parameter $'t'$:

\begin{equation}
 J(t; k) = \int_0^\infty x^k\sin\left(tx^2\right)\:dx
\end{equation}

(This is allowable through the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)). Thus:

\begin{equation}
H(k) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+}  J(t; k)
\end{equation}

Using [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) we now take the Laplace Transform with respect to '$t$'

\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t;k) \right] &= \int_0^\infty x^k\mathscr{L}_t\left[\sin\left(tx^2\right)\right]\:dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k + 2}}{s^2 + x^4}\:dx
\end{align}

As I address here we [find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d) this becomes:

\begin{align}
 \mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t;k) \right] &= \frac{1}{4}\cdot \left(s^2\right)^{\frac{k + 2 + 1}{2} - 1} \cdot B\left(1 - \frac{k + 2 + 1 }{4},  \frac{k + 2 + 1 }{4} \right) = \frac{1}{4} s^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} B\left(1 - \frac{k + 3}{4} , \frac{k + 3}{4}\right)
\end{align}

Using the [relationship between the Gamma and Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) we find:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t;k) \right] = \frac{1}{4} s^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} \Gamma\left(1 - \frac{k + 3}{4}\right) \Gamma\left( \frac{k + 3}{4}\right)
\end{equation}

Using [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) we find:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t;k) \right] = \frac{1}{4} s^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{k + 3}{4}\right) \right)}
\end{equation}

Taking the inverse Laplace Transforms is rather tricky here. To evaluate recall that:

\begin{equation}
 I = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2} H(k) = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left[ \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} J(t;k)\right] 
\end{equation}

In this process we solve for $H(k)$ using

\begin{equation}
H(k) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+}  \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t; k)\right]\right]
\end{equation}

Thus, our definition of $I$ becomes:

\begin{align}
 I &= \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2} H(k) = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left[ \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} J(t;k)\right] = \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left[ \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t; k)\right]\right]\right] \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\mathscr{L}_t\left[J(t; k)\right]\right] =  \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left[ \frac{1}{4} s^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{k + 3}{4}\right) \right)}\right]\right] 
\end{align}

Because I'm lazy, I used Wolframalpha to [evaluate the second derivate at $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdk%5E2%20(1%2F4)*s%5E(%20(k%20-%201)%2F4%20)%20*%20pi%2Fsin(pi*(%20(k%20%2B%203)%2F4))%20at%20k%20%3D%200):

\begin{align}
 I &= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \lim_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left[ \frac{1}{4} s^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{k + 3}{4}\right) \right)}\right]\right] =  \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \frac{\pi}{4}\left( \frac{3\pi^2}{8\sqrt{2}\sqrt{s}} + \frac{\ln^2(s)}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{s}} + \frac{\pi\ln(s)}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{s}}\right)\right] \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \left[ \frac{3\pi^3}{32\sqrt{2}} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right] + \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt{2}} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \frac{\ln^2(s)}{\sqrt{s}}\right]+ \frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt{2}} \mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left[ \frac{\ln(s)}{\sqrt{s}}\right]\right] \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^+} \left[ \frac{3\pi^3}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t}}\right] + \frac{\pi}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\ln(t)\right)^2 -\frac{\pi^2}{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t}}\right]+ \frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\ln(t)}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t}}\right]\right] \\
&= \frac{3\pi^3}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right] + \frac{\pi}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{\pi^2}{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]+ \frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]
\end{align}

Noting [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polygamma(0,1%2F2))
\begin{equation}
\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\gamma - 2\ln(2)
\end{equation}

Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Thus,

\begin{align}
 I = \frac{3\pi^3}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right] + \frac{\pi}{32\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\left(\gamma + 2\ln(2)\right)^2 -\frac{\pi^2}{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]+ \frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt{2}} \left[ \frac{
\gamma - 2\ln(2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right] = \frac{1}{32}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\gamma-\pi+4\ln2)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice solution! I am a fan of your method.

Comment: Do you use a similar technique to evaluate $$F(n)=\int_0^\infty \cos(x^n)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @clathratus  You definitely can

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{R > 0}$ and $\ds{\nu \in \pars{0,1}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{R}x^{\nu}\exp\pars{\ic x^{2}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\pars{R\expo{\ic \theta}}^{\nu}
\exp\pars{\ic R^{2}\expo{2\ic\theta}}R\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta -
\int_{R}^{0}\pars{r\expo{\ic\pi/4}}^{\nu}
\exp\pars{\ic\bracks{r\expo{\ic\pi/4}}^{2}}\expo{\ic\pi/4}\,\dd r
\\[8mm] = &\
-\overbrace{R^{\nu + 1}\,\ic\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\exp\pars{\ic\bracks{\nu\theta + R^{2}\cos\pars{2\theta} + \theta}}
\exp\pars{-R^{2}\sin\pars{2\theta}}\dd\theta}^{\ds{\equiv\ \mc{I}\pars{R,\nu}}}
\\[2mm] + &\
\expo{\ic\pars{\nu + 1}\pi/4}\int_{0}^{R}r^{\nu}\expo{-r^{2}}\dd r
\end{align}

> Since $\ds{\nu \in \pars{0,1}}$, note that

\begin{align}
0 & < \verts{\mc{I}\pars{R,\nu}} <
R^{\nu + 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\expo{-4R^{2}\theta/\pi}\dd\theta =
{\pi \over 4}\,{1 - \exp\pars{-R^{2}} \over R^{1 - \nu}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\LARGE\to}\,\,\,
\color{red}{\large 0}
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\nu}\sin\pars{x^{2}}\dd x} =
\sin\pars{\bracks{\nu + 1}\,{\pi \over 4}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{\nu}\expo{-r^{2}}\dd r
\\[5mm] \stackrel{r^{2}\ \mapsto\ r}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{\nu + 1}\,{\pi \over 4}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{\nu/2 - 1/2}\expo{-r}\dd r =
{1 \over 2}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{\nu + 1}\,{\pi \over 4}}
\Gamma\pars{{\nu \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x}\sin\pars{x^{2}}\dd x} =
\lim_{\nu \to 0^{+}}
\totald[2]{}{\nu}
\braces{{1 \over 2}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{\nu + 1}\,{\pi \over 4}}
\Gamma\pars{{\nu \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 32}\root{\pi \over 2}
\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}2\gamma - \pi + \ln\pars{16}}^{2}} \approx 0.0242
\end{align}