# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\cos x - 1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\ dx$, $0 < \alpha < 1$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I am interested in finding a formula for the evaluation of
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx, \quad 0<\alpha<1.
\end{equation}
I believe the integral exists as an improper integral, however the calculation becomes tricky due to our choice of $\alpha$.  Given the similar look to integrating $\sin x /x$, I decided to try using the Laplace transform.  So I let
\begin{equation}
A(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx) - 1}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx
\end{equation}
and then do
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(A)(t) ={}& \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx) - 1}{x^{1+\alpha}} e^{-st}dx dt\\
={}& \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+\alpha}} \int_0^\infty (\cos(tx) - 1)e^{-st}dtdx\\
={}& \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+\alpha}} \mathcal{L}(\cos(tx) - 1)(t)dx\\
={}& \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+\alpha}} \left( \frac{s}{s^2+x^2} - \frac{1}{s} \right)dx\\
={}& - \frac{1}{s} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{s^2+x^2}dx.
\end{align}

Unfortunately I've found myself unable to solve this improper integral.  Given that our only condition on $\alpha$ is $0 < \alpha < 1$, it doesn't seem to lend itself to trigonometric substitution.  Integration by parts didn't appear to clean anything up either.

I greatly appreciate any clarity or ideas.  To be honest, even if I can solve the last improper integral, I can't be sure the inverse Laplace transform will be clean either; so perhaps my initial approach is where I need work.  Thank you.

Comment: According to Mathematica the integral is equal to $\cos( \pi  \alpha /2) \Gamma(-\alpha)$ for $0<\alpha<2$, which is in agreement with some numerical tests I did. I hope this helps!

Comment: @oreomair In fact, the integral exists for $0<\alpha<2$.  Please see my posted solution and let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @HansOlo While the result you reported was almost correct (you have the wrong sign), that form seems awkward because (1) the appearance of the Gamma function with negative argument, and (2) the not-so-obvious removeable singularity at $\alpha =1$ since $\cos(\pi \alpha/2)\Gamma(-\alpha)$ is indeterminate as $\alpha \to 1$.   Have a look at the solution I posted herein.

Comment: @MarkViola Yeah, there might a typo, sorry

Comment: @HansOlo Well, my message was not specifically sent to alert you the the minus sign error.  Rather, I wanted to emphasize the two points I enumerated. ;-)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382412/ (with $\sin x$ instead of $\cos x - 1$, but the methods are very similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that circumvents use of complex analysis and relies on real analysis only.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

Let $I(\alpha)$, $0<\alpha<2$, be given by the integral

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx$$

Let $f(t)=1-\cos(t)$ and $G(s) = \frac1{s^{1+\alpha}}$.  Then appealing to [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the Laplace Transform, we have

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty \color{blue}{\mathscr{L}\{f\}(x)}
\color{red}{ \mathscr{L^{-1}}\{G\}(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \color{blue}{\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}}\,\,\,\color{red}{\frac{x^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576), I showed using real analysis only that the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is given by

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(\alpha-1)\right)\tag2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ yields for $\alpha\in (0,2)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(1+\alpha)\sin(\pi \alpha/2)}}\tag3\\$$

---

---

**NOTE:  ALTERNATIVE FORM**

Using the reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ for the Gamma function, we can write $(3)$ alternatively as for $\alpha\in (0,2)\setminus { 1}$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(\alpha)=-\cos(\pi \alpha)\Gamma(-\alpha)}\tag4$$

which agrees with previously reported results.

For $\alpha\to 1$, the right-hand side of $(4)$ approaches $\pi/2$.  So, if we define $(4)$ as a function with a removeable discontinuity at $\alpha=1$, the the result holds for $\alpha \in (0,2)$.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer.  Yes, I was aware that it should work for $0 < \alpha < 2$, but was focusing on $0 < \alpha < 1$ for the time being.  Man, I knew the Laplace transform was going in a good direction!

Answer (score 4):

Integrating by parts gives that
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{\alpha}}dx $$
Let $f(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{\alpha}}$ and let $\gamma_R$ be the contour integration $[0,R]\cup\left\{Re^{i\vartheta},\vartheta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\right\}\cup[iR,0]$. Then because $f$ has no singularities inside the contour, we have
$$ \int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz=0 $$
However,
$$ \int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz=\int_0^R f(t)dt+iR\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(Re^{i\vartheta})e^{i\vartheta}d\vartheta-i\int_0^R f(it)dt $$
And,
$$ \left|\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(Re^{i\vartheta})e^{i\vartheta}d\vartheta\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{R^{\alpha}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-R\sin\vartheta}d\vartheta\leqslant\frac{1}{R^{\alpha}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-R\frac{2}{\pi}\vartheta}d\vartheta\ll\frac{1}{R^{1+\alpha}} $$
Therefore
$$ \lim\limits_{R\rightarrow +\infty}iR\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(Re^{i\vartheta})e^{i\vartheta}d\vartheta=0 $$
Taking the limit as $R\rightarrow +\infty$ gives that
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}f(t)dt=i\int_0^{+\infty}f(it)dt $$
That is
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{it}}{t^{\alpha}}dt=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\alpha)}\Gamma(1-\alpha) $$
Taking the imaginary part gives that
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t^{\alpha}}dt=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\alpha)\right)\Gamma(1-\alpha)=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}\right)\alpha\Gamma(-\alpha) $$
We can therefore conclude that
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma(-\alpha) $$
which is the formula given by **Hans Olo** in the comments section.

Comment: Inasmuch as $0<\alpha<1$, the expression $\Gamma(-\alpha)$ seems a bit awkward.  See my solution, which develops the solution using real analysis only and avoids the Gamma function with negative argument.

Comment: I don't understand your point, I used $\Gamma(1-\alpha)$ and then after, I changed it to $-\alpha\Gamma(-\alpha)$ to match the expression in the comment.

Comment: Yes, your answer is not incorrect.  It just seems awkward to express the answer with a Gamma function with negative argument.  In fact, the integral of interest exists for $\alpha \in (0,2)$, whereas your answer does not make this obvious since $\Gamma(-1)$ fails to exist.  Have a look at my solution including the "NOTE" wherein I show the equality of our results.  P.S.  Instead of your using the functional equation, you could have used the reflection formula.

Comment: The gamma function is still on with a negative argument. The awkwardness of the solution is somewhat subjective.

Comment: @HansOlo What is $\Gamma(-1)$?  It doesn't exist.  The indeterminate form as $\alpha\to 1$ makes the awkwardness of your form of the solution less subjective, does it not?

Comment: There is a branch point (or pole when a=1) at the origin.  Need we not be careful about that?

Comment: When $\alpha\rightarrow 1$, $-\cos\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}\right)\sim(1-\alpha)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\Gamma(-\alpha)\sim\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ thus the product converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is the value of the Dirichlet integral and the singularity is removeable.

Comment: @Tuvasbien I believe that I covered this in my posted solution herein.  ;-)

Comment: Both solutions are nice. I just want to add that, if we use complex integration, we also have to add a small quarter-circle around $z=0$ (because this is a singular point). If $\alpha <1$ integral along this small circle $\to0$ at $r\to0$. If $\alpha\in[1;2)$, this integral is non-zero but, due to the fact that it is real, it does not contribute into imaginary part. $\Re\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{it}}{t^{\alpha}}dt$ diverges for $\alpha\in[1;2)$