# Mellin transform of $\sin(x)$.

Tags: improper-integrals, transformation

This is regarding the answer given by @bertrand87
in this post
[Integral $\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha} \sin(x)dx.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271613/integral-int-0-infty-x-alpha-sinxdx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$$\left\{\mathscr{M} \sin\right\}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \sin(x) dx = \Gamma(s)\sin\left(\frac{s\pi}{2}\right)$$

Now, the above identity is valid for $s>0$ as the gamma integral converges for $s>0$.

Subsituing $s=1−a$, we have that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-a} \sin(x) dx = \Gamma(1-a)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{a\pi}{2}\right) = \Gamma(1-a)\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)$$
which is valid for $a<1$.

However, it is mentioned in the answer that the above identity is valid for $a\in(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.
How?

Comment: As far as I know, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \sin(x) dx = \Gamma(s)\sin\left(\frac{s\pi}{2}\right)$$ is valid if $ -1<\Re(s)<1$

Comment: Since that identity was derived using Ramanujan's master theorem ,what then is the range for s, in which RMT is valid? I assumed it valid for s>0 only , which is why I had asked this question.