# Mellin transformation of some functions (divergence problem)

Tags: convergence-divergence, gamma-function, dirac-delta, mellin-transform

I understand the constant can have Mellin transformation
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} dx = 2\pi \delta(i s)
$$
This is related to integration $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} dx \sim \delta(k)
$$

I also know Mellin transformation of $e^{i x}$, which gives $$
\int_0^\infty dx e^{ix} x^{s-1} = \exp\left[\frac{i\pi s}{2} \right] \Gamma(s)
$$
which is also given in this answer:
[Mellin transform of $\sin x$ aka $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{s-1}\sin x dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382412/mellin-transform-of-sin-x-aka-int-infty-0-xs-1-sin-x-dx).
This means trigonometric functions can be Mellin transformed.

Now my question is, can we Mellin transform $\cosh x$ or $\sinh x$? Obviously $$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} e^{-x} dx=\Gamma(s)
$$
But the problem is for $e^x$ part. We understand it is divergent. But I wonder whether there exists any general function like Dirac delta to give an ANSWER to $$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} e^{x} dx =?
$$
like Dirac delta function even though it is divergent

Comment: Have you tried to apply the same kind of contour deformation on the complex plane as in the linked answer ? Alternatively, you can work with a series representation by substituting the $e^x$ by the exponential series.